# Clousure of a sequence

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space and $\{a_n\}$ a bounded sequence. Consider $A = \overline{\{a_n\}}$. Prove that $A$ is compact.

I had different attempts to do the proof but it's quite imposible. Since $X$ is complete compact and sequentially compact are equivalent, so $A$ is compact iff every sequence of $A$ has a convergent subsequence. Anyone can help me? I can’t construct the sequence neither using the classical definition of compactness.

Comment: I don't think this is true. For example let $X$ be a countably infinite set with the discrete metric and let $a_n$ be an enumeration of $X$. Then $A$ is just $X$, which is not compact. The failure of this fact is basically because "not every bounded space is totally bounded".

Comment: In a general metric space, boundedness is not enough. Total-boundedness would be enough, but it's enough for any set, not just a countable one. So nothing interesting in that.

Comment: Just noticed this now, you wrote "Since $X$ is complete compact and sequentially compact are equivalent," this does not require completeness, compactness and sequential compactness are equivalent in arbitrary metric spaces.

Answer (score 2):

This is not true.

Consider $X=\mathbb{R}$ endowed with the metric $d$ defined by $d(x,y)=\min\lbrace |x-y|, 1 \rbrace$.

Let $a_n=n$. The sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded for the metric $d$ (actually, all sequences are bounded for the metric $d$), but $\overline{(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}}$ is definitely not compact.

Comment: Why $\{y_n\}$ has a convergent subsequence?

Comment: @JulianDoyle Oops sorry. I hope this is better now.

Answer (score 1):

It has been pointed out already with specific counter-examples that this statement is not true in general.

In fact, this statement will be true if and only if the given metric space is proper, i.e., all closed bounded subsets are compact (equivalently, closed balls are compact).

To see this, note that it is certainly true for a proper space (since the closure of a bounded sequence is closed and bounded, hence compact).

Conversely if $X$ is nonproper, then there is a noncompact closed bounded set $S\subseteq X$.  Since $S$ is noncompact, there is a sequence $x_n$ in $S$ (hence necessarily bounded) with no convergent subsequence in $S$, and since $S$ is closed, this implies $x_n$ has no convergent subsequence in $X$, and so $\overline{\{x_n\}}$ contains a sequence with no convergent subsequence, and is hence noncompact.

##### Remark

The condition that a metric space $X$ is complete does in fact imply (and is indeed equivalent to) a similar statement.   Namely, $X$ is complete if and only if for every *Cauchy* sequence $a_n$, $\overline{\{a_n\}}$ is compact.

Since every Cauchy sequence is bounded, this is one way to see that every proper space must be complete.